# How can I find all installable versions with brew?

Tags: macos, homebrew

Suppose I have a component `foo` that has versions `2.1`, `2.2`, `2.2.1` and `3.0` available. Suppose I have installed version `2.1`. How do I tell brew to get the latest version in the `2.x` line but not 3.0?

Is there a way to list all available versions?

Is there a way to limit upgrade to the latest version of `2.x`?

Answer (score 11):

The latest version of homebrew gives an error `Error: Unknown command: versions`. This is because `versions` has been obsoleted from homebrew.

Instead, use `brew search elasticsearch`. This will give the available versions of elasticsearch.

Eg. `elasticsearch ✔    elasticsearch@2.4`

Then run `brew install elasticsearch@2.4`

You can check the final elasticsearch version by `elasticsearch --version`

Comment: `brew search` does not display version information with Homebrew 2.4.9

Comment: It doesn't show ALL available versions, but only those already installed on your local machine

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to limit upgrade to the latest version of 2.x?

I don't believe `brew` has a built-in way to specify the latest `2.x`. You'd have to specify `brew install foo@2.9`. You could write a simple bash command using `sort` and `grep` to return it.

> Is there a way to list all available versions?

To get the exact results without extraneous noise, you can use regex with `brew search`. It only returns `foo` and `foo@___`. This is especially helpful if you're searching for a short package name like `r` or `git` that would otherwise return a lot of noise.

```sh
$ brew search '/^foo$|^foo@/'
```

Note, `brew search` does seem to support Extended Regex, so I couldn't use the more efficient regex below. Of course, you could use a grep pipe to accomplish the same:

```sh
$ brew search foo | grep -E '^foo(@.*)?$'
```

Answer (score -2):

Here is what I figured out (I use `elasticsearch` as example):

```
$ brew versions elasticsearch

1.3.2    git checkout 475debf /usr/local/Library/Formula/elasticsearch.rb
...
1.1.0    git checkout c7f653b /usr/local/Library/Formula/elasticsearch.rb
1.0.1    git checkout 9b8103f /usr/local/Library/Formula/elasticsearch.rb
1.0.0    git checkout 1fb5dda /usr/local/Library/Formula/elasticsearch.rb
0.90.11  git checkout 91c60b9 /usr/local/Library/Formula/elasticsearch.rb
0.90.10  git checkout b155496 /usr/local/Library/Formula/elasticsearch.rb
0.90.9   git checkout 28f45d0 /usr/local/Library/Formula/elasticsearch.rb
...
```

Comment: I'm getting `Error: Unknown command: versions`

Comment: The brew versions command has been removed from brew according to an SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17103753/1511504